# Spring @Autowire does not find beans through `mvn verify`

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

I have a Spring (not Spring Boot) project at https://github.com/poggs/spring-autowire-it-problem.

When running the integration test `ExampleComponentIT` through IntelliJ IDEA, both tests pass and the code can find the bean `ExampleComponent`.  When running the integration test with `mvn verify`, it fails as it can't find `ExampleComponent`.

What I want is for `mvn verify` to be able to find `ExampleComponent` as it's executed as part of the CI build process.

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peter, I have fixed this problem by a temporal workaround

> mvn verify -Dfailsafe.useModulePath=false

The fix is already done and it will be released in the version **3.0.0-M6**. There the workaround *useModulePath=false* would not be needed anymore.

Comment: Peter, pls put the like here if it works for you. The people would have bigger chance to find this.

Comment: What _was_ the fix? Can you please point to the commit at https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/commits/master?branch=master, thanks.

Comment: It was solved in the JIRA issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1809

Comment: Code change https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/commit/f9772370749cc9fa19638159f0b29e3be6794614/

Answer (score 1):

It does not make sense to name it an integration test, e.g. `ExampleComponentIT`, if you want to load the classes from `target/classes`.

The version 3.0.0-M5 is right, and you should properly build or guarantee that the JAR file works as expected and then `maven-failsafe-plugin` would work properly with the integration tests.

The difference between Surefire and Failsafe is that Failsafe may fail on `verify` but the Surefire fails on `test` phase. Additionally, the Failsafe plugin uses JAR file instead of `target/classes` which is what the integration test expect due to the `package` phase happens before the phases `integration-test` and `verify`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense!

Comment: Spot on! I was facing the same issue but the class/bean in question actually _is_ contained in the `targer/module.jar`. Yet, it still didn't end up on failsafe's classpath. Also, the "fix" in your answer is line with what Spring recommends at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#integration-tests-no-starter-parent

Comment: Furthermore, in my case the test succeeded when run with surefire rather than with failsafe. `mvn test -pl module -Dtest=MyIT` was ok but `mvn verify -pl module -Dit.test=MyIT` failed.

Comment: Sure, this may happen with -Dit.test=MyIT because Failsafe and Surefire are different. Failsafe uses JAR file of the project, but Surefire uses target/classes.

Answer (score 0):

When running `maven-surefire-plugin`, specifically 3.0.0-M5, through `mvn clean verify`, the directory `target/classes` is not on the classpath.  This directory contains the compiled Java code needed by the integration test.

Adding the following to the `maven-failsafe-plugin` configuration in `pom.xml` fixes the problem:

```
<configuration>
  <additionalClasspathElements>                     
    <additionalClasspathElement>target/classes</additionalClasspathElement>
  </additionalClasspathElements>
</configuration>
```

Alternatively, downgrading to 3.0.0-M4 works.

Comment: Don't do it this way. Failsafe uses JAR file but Surefire uses target/classes. So it is not a fault of the plugins. You have to see what;s the difference between classes and the JAR. Maybe some classes manipulation, bytecode weaving, or so.