# SeekTool - what can that be?

Tags: java, maven

When doing a `mvn test` on a Java project on Win10 I get 2 failure notes:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] SeekTools:     Seek for the Project Tool Folder (give option '-h' for help)
[ERROR] ERROR: reached root of filesystem
```

... test runs smoothly, but Surefire reports:

```
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[ERROR] There are test failures.
```

I am using Maven 3.6.3 and Java 11.0.10 on Win10.

When doing the same to the same project on Debian-10, I get no such errors. Here I am using Maven 3.6.0 and Java 11.0.9.

I doubt that the small version difference causes the failures. But I got no clue how to start to solve them. Google did not help.

I am applying the plugins

```
maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.1
maven-surefire-plugin 3.0.0-M5
```

Do you got any hint for me how to approach this problem?

The complete output is [here](https://pastebin.com/BDXpDYNx).
The pom.xml is [here](https://pastebin.com/mYgmdau7)

Comment: Remove <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore> and then upload the XML reports (see target/surefire-reports) and the logs.

Comment: Additionally, see the workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65693223/spring-autowire-does-not-find-beans-through-mvn-verify

Comment: You may [download](https://owncloud.august.de/index.php/s/N15eMbe4K5LpfqM/download) the XML report. Where to find log files? Seems that all output of Surefire went to the console as referenced above. There is no dump file. With 3.0.0-M4 the failure is reduced to _Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log_ ... _ForkStarter.java:662_

Comment: I could solve the _Error occurred in starting fork..._ by adding `     <forkCount>0</forkCount>` to the Surefire plugin configuration. That is: I am done for this issue.

Comment: <forkMode>never</forkMode> avoids the fork error, too.

Answer (score 0):

@ngong
`<forkCount>0</forkCount>` and `<forkMode>never</forkMode>` is not a fix.
You are using JDK11. I guess you do not use JPMS.
We have a bug in Surefire and you can workaround it by **`<useModulePath>false</useModulePath>`**.
Setting `forkCount` to zero or `forkMode` to `never` is inherently wrong idea in this case because any changes in the environment may affect your tests on any machine.
Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65806777/2758738

Comment: See the same answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66304577/2758738

Comment: I guess your idea would not help me much. tibor17. My projects are dependent on JPMS. (xmlbeans.apache is creating a module from an xml schema, which I am using in application modules). I am wondering how long it takes until JPMS is widely supported. forkCount=0 does the trick. My tests are sufficiently executed.

Comment: no, no, it's bad that you use forkCount=0, for sure. The plugin has to work without forkCount=0. The JPMS means for Surefire that you have src/main/java/module-info.java or you have it compiled in target/classes/module-info.class. The thing that you forkCount=0 means that Surefire ignores JPMS and all dependencies are in a pure ClassLoader. I think you need to use module-info.java in src/test/java but of course I do not see your project. Please send me your POM to my email and I can help. Please see our documentation https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/jpms.html

Comment: Interesting idea to have multiple module-info.java in a project. I will contact you.