# Maven ignoring tests on build

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Currently trying to test a project and for some reason, it won't run the tests when using `mvn clean install`. Strangely enough though, right-clicking on the project and do `Run 'All Tests'` on Intellij, runs all the tests well.

The folder is called `test`, with the tests having a `Test` added after the name of the class they are testing. I have this configuration in the POM file set up:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>
```

with the java version being set as such: `<java.version>11</java.version>`

and the junit dependency being set like so:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
```

This will result in:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ ******* ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Usually I don't need to even add the `maven-surefire-plugin` under the plugins tag, although I did this to specify the version, maybe that might help but it's of no use.

Any idea what the issue might be?

## UPDATE 1:

Added some configuration for the surefire plugin: `<useModulePath>false</useModulePath>`

Logs from `mvn -X test`: https://controlc.com/0e9faba9

Comment: how are your test classes named? I'm having hard time believing you will only have test classes named "test.java". Normally they would need to be named xxxTest.java to be picked up by maven, where xxx is some prefix.

Comment: this is working as expected :)   https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html    How are your test classes named ?  They should match the expression written on the include and of course being placed on the folder that maven expects it

Comment: Apologies. The tests are the same name of the classes to test, with the added `Test` at the end. But they are all in a folder called `test`. I just had a sudden realization though that the custom config I  was adding was checking for the actual name of the file. So it makes sense that I don't need to have custom include tags since the names are following the default naming convention. Updating question to remove the extra bad details

Comment: Probably 1) tests are not annotated with @Test 2) test classes are outside of maven's `test` directory

Comment: @Antoniossss tests are all annotated with the `@Test` and I can run them manually. The `test` directory is in the same level as the `main`

Comment: But maybe you did some tweaks and the test directory is not the default test location. You could share effective pom maybe?

Comment: @Antoniossss https://pastebin.com/6edTz7qp This should be everything, apart from the confidential stuff

Comment: add it to the question.

Comment: The answer in already in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66605008/seektool-what-can-that-be?noredirect=1#comment117750898_66605008

Comment: @NathanielCutajar your pastebin pom does not even have the surefire plugin that you have in the question? please update the question with your full pom to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @NathanielCutajar Can we continue in the chat? You was invited!

Comment: The version **3.0.0-M6** has been deployed to the Maven Central repository. The workaround **useModulePath=false** can be removed in your POM now.

Comment: The version **3.0.0-M6** has 111 fixes and it supports the latest JDK 18 and Maven 3.8.5 as well. We will start a new Release Vote for **2.22.3** on the Apache Maven dev mailing list. The version **2.22.3** has 23 backported bug fixes and it supports JDK 18 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version **3.0.0-M6** has been deployed to the Maven Central repository.
This issue is fixed.
Pls check the POM and the configuration **useModulePath=false** as a workaround.
http://quabr.com:8182/66637732/maven-ignoring-tests-on-build
Now the workaround can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we have a bug in surefire 3.0.0-M5 (when JDK 9+ and no JPMS is used) but we published the workaround on the Stackoverflow several times.

Pls check it out with a temporal workaround

> mvn test -Dsurefire.useModulePath=false

The fix is already done and it will be released in the version `3.0.0-M6`. There the workaround `useModulePath=false` would not be needed anymore.

Comment: Both workarounds did not fix the issue. I am still having no tests run. Even when dropping back to  the default 2.22.2 maven surefire version

Comment: Both workarounds? I published only one: -Dsurefire.useModulePath=false

Comment: 2.22.x processes the dependencies different way than the latest versions. It would be nice to see your entire project and we can try to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Another alternative would be to have debug logs. Pls run the build (mvn -X test) catch the logs a publish them. Maybe we would see the issue immediately.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. What I meant to say is that I tried to run the command you gave me, and I also tried to add it as a configuration in the plugin. Both ways did not work. I am more inclined to use it as a config though rather than as a parameter to run it. I also added the logs when running it with the 3.0.0-M5 version in the question

Comment: Try to click on your link https://pastebin.com/tdqv4L3P because there is HTTP 404, not found.

Comment: Pastebin kept deleting my save so I had to use another service. Updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229980/discussion-between-tibor17-and-nathaniel-cutajar).

Comment: @NathanielCutajar Can we continue in the chat? You was invited!